# Subprocess with Popen cant get `return` value

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to open another script in main program using `Subprocess.Popen`

```
import subprocess
import threading
from queue import Queue


class SubprocessThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, command, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.command = command
        self.output_queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            self.command,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )

        for line in process.stdout:
            self.output_queue.put(line.strip().decode())

        for line in process.stderr:
            self.output_queue.put(line.strip().decode())

        process. Wait()

        # input None as end of the process
        self.output_queue.put(None)

    def get_output(self):
        results = []
        while True:
            result = self.output_queue.get()
            if result is None:
                break
            results.append(result)
        return results[:-1], results[-1]


outputQueue = Queue()
subprocess_thread = SubprocessThread(['python', './subprocess_script.py'], output_queue=outputQueue)
subprocess_thread.start()  #
subprocess_thread.join()

output, result = subprocess_thread.get_output()
print(output, result)
```

and the `subprocess_script.py` is very easy, it prints a number 2 and returns 2 at the same time

```
def func():
    print(1 + 1)
    return 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func()
```

but when I debug the main program I only see the `print` value in output queue
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ldsi.png)

how to get the `return` value at the same time

Comment: Why not just `import subprocess_script` and then call `subprocess_script.func()` ?

Comment: In the `if __name__==__main__` block just `print(func())` ?

Comment: After constructing Popen you'll need *process.communicate()*

Comment: @diogeek yeah it's a solution but for some reasons I have to do like this

Comment: @ShepardMerose In that case, it won't work